# How to remove whitespace inside a div and between divs

Tags: html, css, layout, padding

So, I'm having quite a problem removing whitespace from this div.
There is what looks like left and top padding inside the block and also top margin outside the block.

The block I'm messing with is with a border.

[The Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ricMG.png)

I have already tried setting the padding and the margin of the block to 0, but that has changed nothing.

CSS code:

```css
#header{
 color:white;
 background-color:#009933;
 font-weight:bold;
 max-width:1024px;
 height:100px;
 padding-right:30px;
 font-size:150%;
}
#footer{
 color:white;
 background-color:#009933;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 max-width:1024px;
 height:60px;
 padding:10px;
}
#text{
 display:inline-block;
 color:solid black;
 background-color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
 max-width:700px;
 margin-left:100px; 
}
#navigation{
 color:#009933;
 background-color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
    max-width:224px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which div in the image are you referring to, specifically?

Comment: is that a list? If so, that spacing is likely coming from the default margin and padding that comes with `<ul>` elements. Set `margin: 0; padding: 0;` on your list element. It'd be helpful if you included your HTML.

Comment: Hey @imajhu, thats a list. I followed your advice and I was able to remove the whitespace between the unordered list ant the left of the page. But unfortunately I was not able to remove the whitespace between the div and the header.

Comment: share your html code as well.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#header{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
 color:white;
 background-color:#009933;
 font-weight:bold;
 max-width:1024px;
 height:100px;
 padding-right:30px;
 font-size:150%;
}
#footer{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
 color:white;
 background-color:#009933;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 max-width:1024px;
 height:60px;
 padding:10px;
}
#text{
 display:inline-block;
 color:solid black;
 background-color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
 max-width:700px;
 margin-left:100px; 
}
#navigation{
 color:#009933;
 background-color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
    max-width:224px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTML in your snippet but assuming that you coded the navigation as a list you need to put padding/margin of 0 on your UL and or LIs.